# making a foreach loop inside an SQL query or do it dynamically via PHP?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have 2 tables in my DB, Polyptychs and Illustrations. The PK of Polyptychs is FK in Illustrations.
What I want to do is:

```
SELECT polyptychID FROM Polyptychs
```

and subsequently, foreach ID returned I need all illustrations.
Via PHP the solution is something like this(using PDO sintax):

```
<?php
//create the connection with DB
$sql = "SELECT polyptychID, polyptych_image FROM Polyptychs";
$stmt = $this->DBH->query($sql);
$resultTmp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final_result  = array();
foreach($resultTmp as $val){
  $id = $val['polyptychID'];
  $final_result["$id"]["image"] = $val['polyptych_image'];
  $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Illustrations WHERE polyptychID = :polyID";
  $stmt2 = $this->DBH->prepare($sql2);
  $stmt2->execute(array('polyID' => $id));
  $resultTmp2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $final_result["$id"]["illustrations"] = $resultTmp2;
  unset($id);
  unset($sql2);
  unset($stmt2);
  unset($resultTmp2);
}
?>
```

Now `$final_result` contains all `polyptychID` as key of the array and its relative image and illustrations (if there's no error in the code).
What I want to know is if there is an easier way to get it, maybe doing it via SQL, and what is the best solution.
Thanks

Comment: Whatever is wrong with a `JOIN`? And why `prepare` the same query over and over, why not re-use a single prepared statement?

Comment: is there a reason you can't do this in one query, and group the results on the PHP side? `SELECT P.polyptychID, P.polyptych_imge, I.* FROM Polypytchs AS P LEFT OUTER JOIN Illustrations AS I ON P.polyptychID = I.polyptychID;`?

Comment: why do you have images in both tables?

Comment: Because are not the same image. PlantTheIdea with a LEFT JOIN then i have illustration without a polyptych in the table with value NULL in Polyptych fields, and need to filtrate the result via PHP.

Comment: @Andrea_86: Then don't use a `LEFT JOIN`, which allows for `NULL`'s in the left joined table, and go for an `INNER JOIN`, as I explained in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do, if I were you:

```
SELECT p.polyptychID as ID,
    p.polyptych_image as image,
    i.*
FROM Polyptychs p
INNER JOIN Illustrations i
    ON i.polyptychID = p.polyptychID
```

In light of your comment, check this handy graph to understand why an `INNER JOIN` is what I chose to use here:
[image: Join graph]

Then, to format the array in the way you want it, just write this:

```
$formatted = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $id = $row['ID'];
    if (!isset($formatted[$id]))
    {
        $formatted[$id] = array(
            'image' => $row['image'],
            'illustrations' => array() //we'll set this in a minute
        );
    }
    unset($row['ID'], $row['image']);//remove id & image values
    $formatted[$id]['illustrations'][$row['illustrationsID']] = $row;//assign rest of result-set
}
```

Of course, if there are fields in the `Illustrations` called either `ID` or `image`, then you'd have to change the query to `p.polyptychID AS p_ID` or something. Just make sure the aliasses are unique and you'll be fine.

On the re-use of prepared statements, it seems to be something people tend to overlook, but you really can use the same prepared statements over and over. As luck would have it, in fact, I [wrote an answer about this matter just this morning](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45147/want-to-check-if-i-am-using-pdo-correctly/45192#45192). I use some basic examples that might be applicable to your case, too. So if -for some reason- you can't do a join, you can simply write:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM Illustrations WHERE polyptychID = :pId'
);
$baseStmt = $pdo->query(
    'SELECT polyptychID, polyptych_image FROM Polyptychs'
);
$result = array()
while($row = $baseStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $result[$row['polyptychID']] = array(
        'image' => $row['polyptych_image'],
        'illustrations' => null
    );
    $stmt->execute( array(':pId' => $row['pId']));
    $result[$row['polyptychID']]['illustrations'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: didn't understand why assign ['illustrations'] later, and multiple row have different illustration of the same polyptych, and in this way you simply store the last ['illustration']

Comment: @Andrea_86: I assign it later to unset the `image` and `ID` bits from the result array first, I'll edit my answer to avoid reassigning the `illustrations` key, though

Comment: nice overview, thank. The " re-use of prepared statements" maybe was only a typing error, the second prepare was for $sql2 variable.

Comment: @Andrea_86: What typo? I prepare a statement outside a loop, and then simply re-use it in a loop. That's to show that you don't have to call prepare over and over, just call `execute` on the `PDOStatement` instance, passing new values and you're done: less overhead from the `prepare` calls

Comment: ah ok, i didn't had understand what you means..yeah you're correct, i had wrote that code fast just for explain my problem, didn't look to optimize it

Comment: @Andrea_86: Ok, BTW, if one of the answers solved your problem, then please mark that answer as accepted, as is asked of the users of this site in the help section

Answer (score 1):

You could run just one query using Inner Join:

```
SELECT P.polyptychID, polyptych_image, I.* 
FROM Polyptychs P
INNER JOIN Illustrations I ON I.polyptychID = p.polyptychID
```

Now you loop the results adding them to the same array structure `polyptychID` as keys and `illustrations` as an array:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT P.polyptychID, polyptych_image, I.* 
        FROM Polyptychs P
        INNER JOIN Illustrations I ON I.polyptychID = p.polyptychID";
$stmt = $this->DBH->query($sql);
$resultTmp = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final_result  = array();
foreach($resultTmp as $val){
    $id = $val['polyptychID'];
    $final_result["$id"]["image"] = $val['polyptych_image'];
            // I'm not sure what's the ID for Illustration table, so I'll assume `illustrationID`
    $final_result["$id"]["illustrations"][$val["illustrationID"]] = $val;
    unset($id);
}
?>
```

Comment: $final_result["$id"]["illustrations"][] = $val; without key?!?
furthermore i re-write more times $final_result["$id"]["image"] because all row with the same $id have the same image, a waste

Comment: Sorry @Andrea_86, just fixed it setting (the assumed) `illustrationID` as key for the `illustrations` array.